# Resume uploading files after connection is back up

Tags: c#, methods, console-application

I'm using [Kellerman .NET SFTP Library](http://www.kellermansoftware.com/p-41-net-sftp-library.aspx?mode=Specifications&) and I'm struggling with one of the methods.

> [ResumeUploadFileAsync (Method)](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/NetSFTPLibrary/KellermanSoftware.NET-SFTP-Library/SFTP/M/ResumeUploadFileAsync)

According to the [documentation](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/NetSFTPLibrary/KellermanSoftware.NET-SFTP-Library/SFTP/M/ResumeUploadFileAsync) I can call this method to resume the file upload after the connection is back up.

```
sftp.ResumeUploadFileAsync("c:\\uploadfile1.txt", "uploadfile1.txt");
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the concept of the `ResumeUploadFileAsync` but what I'm trying to accomplish is during the upload if I lose internet connection and it's up in few minutes I want my application to start the upload from where it left of.

I'm writing this in C# console application.

This is the approach I took:

```
 public static void uploadToSFTP()
 {
   try
     {
            SFTP myConnection = new SFTP();
            myConnection.EnableLogging();
            myConnection.HostAddress = "tt-sftp";
            myConnection.UserName = "username";
            myConnection.Password = "pwd";
            myConnection.CurrentDirectory = "sam";
            myConnection.Connect();

           //upload file
            myConnection.UploadFileAsync(yesterdaysZipFile, localZipFileName);


            bool isConnected = false;

            while (myConnection.IsBusy == true)
            {
                //PRINT HOW LONG REMAINING FROM UPLOAD
                if (myConnection.IsConnected == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(myConnection.EstimatedTimeRemaining);
                }
                else
                {
                    //check for connection
                    while (isConnected == false)
                    {
                        if (myConnection.IsConnected == true)
                        {
                            //resume the upload
                            myConnection.ResumeUploadFileAsync(yesterdaysZipFile, localZipFileName);
                            while (myConnection.IsBusy == true)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(myConnection.EstimatedTimeRemaining);
                            }
                            isConnected = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            isConnected = false;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
          List<FTPFileInfo> _files = myConnection.GetDirectoryListing();

          //there's more code here but it never gets to this point

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

I have enabled logging to see what's happening.

When I lose connection to Internet I get the following error which is understandable.

> Message: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No such host is kn
>   own

Then I enable back my Internet connection and this is what I get:

> open "****@tt-sftp" 22
>
>   0 Connected
>
>   Pass: ****
>   0 Password Accepted
>   ReconnectRetry: Force connect successful
>   ResumeUploadFileAsync \tt-e\CompressedArchive\20140926\20140926.zip,
>    20140926.zip
>   ReconnectRetry: pwd successful
>   Disconnect
>   0 Disconnected from server
>   GetFileSize 20140926.zip
>   open "****@tt-sftp" 22
>
>   0 Connected
>
>   Pass: ****
>   0 Password Accepted
>   ReconnectRetry: Reconnect successful
>   pwd
>   0 Current directory is: "/"
>   cd /sam
>   cd /sam
>   0 Directory is now /sam
>   stat 20140926.zip
>   0 Directory is now /sam
>   0 Size 0
>   00:00:00
>   00:00:00
>       Message: Can't open file
>       Source: KellermanSoftware.NET-SFTP-Library
>       Target Site:
>       Stack Trace:    at KellermanSoftware.NetSFtpLibrary.Implementation.ChannelSf
>       tp.put(InputStream src, String dst, SftpProgressMonitor monitor, Int32 mode)
>       at KellermanSoftware.NetSFtpLibrary.Implementation.ExternalSFTPChannel.PutBin
>       ary(Stream localStream, String remoteFileName, Int64 restart, IFireProgress fire
>       Progress)
>       GetDirectoryListing sam/
>       ls . sam/

When I go to SFTP, I actually see the .zip file but it only contains one file inside of (missing the others) it and it's corrupted. I can't view it nor download it back using SFTP Client FileZilla.

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this using my approach or is there a better an easier way I can start the upload again when internet connection is back up?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no coding required. It's a built in function of the library. Few things I learned:

```
sftp.ResumeUploadFileAsync("c:\\uploadfile1.txt", "uploadfile1.txt");
```

This method is ONLY to be used if you have functionality in your program that allows your users to stop the upload. This method will allow them to start that upload again.

If it's a console application and you're using `try {} catch {}` statement, make sure you have `Console.ReadLine()` in your `catch` statement. Otherwise, the application will be closed and will not be able to retry the upload.